# Mpf finance display ohlc on graph

Tags: display, ohlc, mpf

On the graph window the y (the ordinate) are displayed but i would like the Open, High, Low and Close of the candle my cursor is on to be displayed

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeK3k.png)

That is it

Read documentation
Searched on stack & internet